# adding ADF runtime extenion into wildfly

Tags: wildfly, oracle-adf

How can I add ADF runtime   essentials into Wildfly10 so I can develop and deploy my adf application on wildfly

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ADF Essentials option - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/adfessentials-1719844.html

Full ADF requires WebLogic, but the Essentials can run on other servers:
https://pinboard.in/search/u:OracleADF?query=ADF_Essentials

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already  download and configured ADF essentials in wildfly10 and after try  and error I added manually the missing jars according to server log but after that an error that I dont understand as follows:classDefFoundError: Failed to link oracle/adf/controller/faces/lifecycle/ADFPhaseListener (Module "deployment.Test1.ear:main" from Service Module Loader): oracle/adf/controller/v2/context/LifecycleContextBuilder